# Installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 10 - Cant Load - Laptop

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, windows

I have a laptop ASUS X555L (i5, 6RAM).
Used only windows before. I need ubuntu for developing rails, django, so have not dealed with os installations.

1. I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04(ISO) through torrent from official website.
2. I've made a USB using WinSetupFromUSB, loaded it from bios then on ubuntu made a partition for "/" (ext4)(/dev/sda9) then used that partition and successfully installed ubuntu there, then got a message to reboot. Rebooted into windows boot manager without a choice. And now **i can't load into installed ubuntu.**
3. If I'm trying to install it again it says - "already installed".
4. Tried boot repair disc - no internet connection, but on ubuntu 14.04 i had.
5. Tried easyBCD, but it adds entry only to windows boot manager, so it thinks that it is another version of windows and gives a error.

I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: have you disabled fast boot from windows?

Comment: no, I unchecked that box now, reloaded, and everything still same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot into Windows - disable hibernation and Fast Boot.
Open command prompt as administrator and execute:

```
powercfg /h off
```

Open Windows Control Panel, go to Power Settings.
Enable show hidden settings - uncheck Fast startup.

Shutdown the machine completely, do NOT reboot.
Boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu as default system.

In case something is messed up from your earlier attempts ... reinstall the GRUB boot loader.

Boot from the Ubuntu installation media.
(select the USB entry with UEFI in front)
Choose Try Ubuntu without installing.
On the Live desktop open a terminal.
Execute the following commands :

```
sudo mount /dev/sda9 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
```

Note:

`sda` = disk | `sda1` = efi partition | `sda9` = system partition (taken from provided screenshot)

To identify the partition numbers use GParted - it is included in the Ubuntu installation media.

**Update addressing your response that you are not able to reinstall the boot loader :**

Boot from the Ubuntu installation media - select the USB entry with UEFI in front.
Choose Try Ubuntu without installing - open GParted and format sda9 with ext4.
Start the Ubuntu installation - when asked what to do - choose Something else.
Select sda9 for Ubuntu - choose ext4 as file system and set / as mount point.
Choose sda for the boot loader being installed to and start the installation.
When finished, boot into BIOS - select Ubuntu as default system to boot.

Comment: I turned off. Boot on bios, started Ubuntu from USB(I got UEFI: IS917 innostor and same line below without UEFI below Boot Override string) I don't have Ubuntu when USB is not connected. What should I choose to run live desktop? How those sd*s can look for example? I got setup on /dev/sda9

Comment: http://imgur.com/OrIF8w1

Comment: I started executing your commands, and get a error when executed "grub-install /dev/sda" Warning: this GDP partition label contains no bios boot partition. embedding won't be possible. another warning saying about blocklists then error: will not proceed with blocklists

Comment: @MaxSlob : Which version of Ubuntu did you install - 32 bit or 64 bit ?

Comment: 64bit version (OS type). name of the .iso file contain 'amd64'

Comment: @MaxSlob : okay - this is the correct version - try it again - important : boot the USB with the UEFI entry in front of Ubuntu ! :)

Comment: no luck( same error

Comment: @MaxSlob :  Then there must have been something going wrong with the system installation - I updated the answer with instructions how to install Ubuntu correctly - please report back the results - good luck ! :)

Comment: reinstalled - working good. Solution was - installing Ubuntu alongside windows boot manager, not the windows itself. Thank you for help.

Comment: @MaxSlob : You're welcome ... I am really glad that you've got it done ... enjoy ubuntu experience ! :)